How to locally read Maildir archives in Windows?
How can I locally open a read-only Maildir backup archive in Windows in order to browse through e-mails, run keyword searches, filter/sort by date or recipient, extract attachments, display e-mails chronologically vs. as conversations etc.? The archive was pulled directly from the mail server by the administrator of a company's IT department (who, unfortunately, is no longer available for support).
For privacy reasons, I do not want to upload the archive to a remote e-mail server.
Here is a screenshot of the folder structure. The files inside the cur folders all have names such as
5286806512.M446716P63625.mail,S=1879880,W=2290677_2,Sa
5286806512.M256849P63625.mail,S=4059,W=6731_2,FS
5286806512.M860467P63625.mail,S=19629,W=43009_2,S


This is false excuse:

For privacy reasons, I do not want to upload the archive to a remote e-mail server.

You can build your own private "remote e-mail server" inside a VM and upload there, not violating any privacy.

However, these files are just on-the-wire email data; Windows software often refers to them as to "eml" files. Just add this extension to them: rename 5286806512.M446716P63625.mail,S=1879880,W=2290677_2,Sa  into 5286806512.M446716P63625.mail,S=1879880,W=2290677_2,Sa.eml and you can then conveniently import it into e.g. Thunderbird.

P.S. It's always worth looking inside a file with some ASCII viewer (or even HEX viewer) if you don't know what to do with it. It may give useful hints.
